# Automate Chrome with window handle

Tags: c, google-chrome, window-handles

I am working on a project in c which i am trying to simulate chrome browsing.
my only difficult is to find a way to get links position on screen after i receive a handle to chrome window. anyone knows how to get the links position??

i am familiar with selenium and managed to do so in python but i require to do so in c too.

any ideas?

```
int wmain()
{
HWND hwnd = NULL;
for (;;)
{
    hwnd = FindWindowEx(0, hwnd, L"Chrome_WidgetWin_1", 0);
    if (!hwnd) 
        break;
    ////Get Links position
}
```

Comment: Your post  in its current form is too broad and not a good fit for Stack Overflow. Please visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read the section [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: thank you for your remarks but i am asking for a way to get links positions on screen in chrome with c.
i don`t think it is so broad but i will look at it again